# Align to the Center of a table cell in two different cells

Tags: html, css, css-position

In the below HTML code . Please find code at "[Center align](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbmQpB) "

**CSS**

```
.QuestionnaireGroupQuestionContainer table td {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .tabularOptionsHeader input {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .tabularOptions label {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .tabularOptions {
        border-spacing: 0px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<body class="QuestionnaireGroupQuestionContainer">
<table class="tabularOptionsHeader">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="QuestionOptions">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <label>1. (Slet ikke relevant)</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="tabularOptions">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="QuestionOptions">
                    <input type="radio" />
                    <label>
                        1. (Slet ikke relevant)
                    </label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have two tables mainly with the class **tabularOptionsHeader** and **tabularOptions**

1. The first table class contains a row with a span containing a radio button and a label for it
2. The second table class contains another row with a radio button and the label both being identical .

I need to display the first table as a header and the the second table as body which will have multiple options basically a tabular format of radio button list with the top most row being the header.

I am able to achive this by using CSS and setting the first table input type radio to ***visibility:hidden*** and the second table i set the label visibility to hidden.

Below is the output.

[image]

I need to align these header text and the radio button to the center of their respective cells but im not able to do so mainly because of setting of the ***visibility*** css attribute that i have set to .

I cannot use the ***display:none*** because i need to have the exact width for the column which contains the text and also the column which contains the radio button in two different tables.

Is it possible using CSS that i could achieve center aligning of both the text and the radio button present in two different tables ?

Adding the row in the second table to the first table cannot be done becuase the output is of two seperate tables.

Comment: Why do you have two separate tables and not just have one table?

Comment: This is a simplified version of the HTML the actual html is a asp.net web control where the each table here is a RadioButtonList.Hence multiple tables

Comment: Can you post your ASP.Net web control code please?

Comment: This is the reason why I don't use ASP.Net Web Controls, even though the project I work on is in ASP.Net. They offer no flexibility at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try like this:**

```css
table.t td {
  text-align: center;
}
table.t td input {
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
table.tt td {
  text-align: center;
}
table.tt td input {
  position: relative;
}
table.tt td label {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table class="t" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="200">
        <input type="radio" />
        <label>1. (Slet ikke relevant)</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" />
        <label>1. (Slet ikke relevant)</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 
<table  class="tt" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td  width="200">
        <input type="radio" />
        <label>1. (Slet ikke relevant)</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" />
        <label>1. (Slet ikke relevant)</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the width="200px"  and use the width taken up by the text "1. (Slet ikke relevant)"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that I suggest you need to change your DOM:

```css
table th, table td {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1. (Slet ikke relevant)</th>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" /></td>                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If this is impossible to do in your back-end, then I would suggest JavaScript.

Comment: Isnt it possible to some kind of css positioning for the input element so that it aligns itself to the center of the td . Basically over lapping on the label whose visibility is set to hidden?